# Add Object to relationship entity

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, relationship

[image]

How would I add new MinorGoal to an existing goal? 
And how to fetch Goal's MinorGoals?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like there should be an image in this post, but it's missing? Can you edit your post with the image, or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate NSManagedObject Entities, `Goal` class will have an `NSSet` called `toMinorGoal` (assuming, your `toMinorGoal` is unordered relationship). Also, XCode will generate 4 accessory methods to add/remove `MinorGoal` objects to/from relationship.

If you need to fetch MinorGoals object, you would just need to get `Goal` object and then access its `toMinorGoals NSSet` that will contain all of its `MinorGoal` objects. Alternatively, you can just fetch `MinorGoal` objects, but these will return every single one of them (if you don't specify how many you want).

This is an approximate example of generated accessors XCode will provide you with:

```
- (void)addtoMinorGoaObject:(MinorGoal *)value;
- (void)removetoMinorGoalObject:(MinorGoal *)value;
- (void)addtoMinorGoal:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removetoMinorGoal:(NSSet *)value;
```

Comment: Okay I get it, one more thing, when I add new MinorGoal, does it matter what ManagedObjectContext I'm using? it has to be "goal.managedObjectContext", or is it okay using "self.managedObjectContext"?

Comment: If goal.managedObjectContext and self.managedObjectContext point to the same managedObjectContext then it is ok.

Comment: okay, but when I come to fetch a certain "MinorGoal", there's no such a [MySet objectAtIndex:indexPath]; so how would I fetch a certain "MinorGoal" from a set if the only thing I have is it's indexPath

Comment: NSSet doesn't have objectAtIndex: method. You can either loop through every single method or call allObject: on MySet to return an array.